MediatR IRequestHandler fails to resolve scoped service when ISender is injected through ICarterModule constructor
Im working on a Clean Architecture course at the moment and found myself trying to structure my minimal api using Carter package. The problem I am currently struggling to understand is why mediatR handler is unabled to resolve the "ISubscriptionRepository" service.
I will provide some code snippets that illustrate the current state of the of the api, that is, program.cs, mediatR handler and endpoint class.
public class SubscriptionEndpoints : ICarterModule
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public SubscriptionEndpoints(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public void AddRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
    {
        var subscriptionEndpoints = app.MapGroup("/Subscription");

        subscriptionEndpoints.MapPost("/", CreateSubscription);
    }

    public async Task<IResult> CreateSubscription(CreateSubscriptionRequest request, ISender _mediator)
    {
        var command = new CreateSubscriptionCommand(request.SubscriptionType.ToString(), request.AdminId);

        var createSubscriptionResult = await _mediator.Send(command); //**Error here**

        return createSubscriptionResult.MatchFirst(
            subscription => Results.Ok(new SubscriptionResponse(subscription.Id, request.SubscriptionType)),
            error => Results.Problem()
        );
    }
}

public class CreateSubscriptionCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateSubscriptionCommand, ErrorOr<Subscription>>
{
    private readonly ISubscriptionRepository _subscriptionRepository;

    public CreateSubscriptionCommandHandler(ISubscriptionRepository subscriptionRepository)
    {
        _subscriptionRepository = subscriptionRepository;
    }

//MediatR handler fails to run because its unable to resolve "ISubscriptionRepository"
    public async Task<ErrorOr<Subscription>> Handle(CreateSubscriptionCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {   
        var subscription = new Subscription
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            SubscriptionType = command.SubscriptionType
        };

        await _subscriptionRepository.AddSubscriptionAsync(subscription);

        return subscription;
    }
}


//PROGRAM.CS
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    builder.Services.AddCarter();   

    builder.Services
        .AddApplication()
        .AddInfrastructure();

}

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapCarter();
app.Run();

public static IServiceCollection AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMediatR(options =>
    {
        options.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining(typeof(DependencyInjection));
    });

    return services;
}

public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ISubscriptionRepository, SubscriptionRepository>();

    return services;
}


Here is a screenshot right before the app crashes, showing that the ISubscriptionRepository is within the mediator instace services list.

As the code suggets through the methods "AddApplication" and "AddInfrastructure", mediatR and repositories are added to the DI container properly. This same functionality works if I use the mediatR interface directly on the request method as parameter instead of injecting it through the ICarterModule constructor, like so:
public async Task<IResult> CreateSubscription(CreateSubscriptionRequest request, ISender _mediator)

I dont understand why the first approach does not work, since even on debugging mode ISubscriptionRepository is within service descriptor list of mediatR instance.
Apologies for the long introduction, thought that some context was needed to understand the issue.
Thanks in advance

have tried to put debug point in handler method to check whether it hit debug point ?

as per my understanding this is a lifetime issue of the registered dependencies

Greetings @pl-jay, just edited the question to add a debugging screenshot.

Can you add full exception here as text

Here it is: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve 'MediatR.IRequestHandler2[GymManagement.Application.Subscriptions.Commands.CreateSubscription.CreateSubscriptionCommand,ErrorOr.ErrorOr1[GymManagement.Domain.Subscriptions.Subscription]]' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'GymManagement.Application.Common.Interfaces.ISubscriptionRepository'.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(ServiceCallSite callSite, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)...

yes it's a dependency lifetime issue

Here have to handle in ICommand interface.


public interface ICommand<out TResponse> : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    //any operation based on need 
}



Command Handler Interface


public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResponse>
    : IRequestHandler<TCommand, TResponse>
    where TCommand : ICommand<TResponse>
{
}



Implementation Command handler


public class CreateSubscriptionCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateEmbargoTypeCommand, EmbargoTypeDto>
{
 private readonly ISubscriptionRepository _subscriptionRepository;

public CreateSubscriptionCommandHandler(ISubscriptionRepository 
subscriptionRepository)
{
    _subscriptionRepository = subscriptionRepository;
}


public async Task<ErrorOr<Subscription>> Handle(CreateSubscriptionCommand 
command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{   
    var subscription = new Subscription
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        SubscriptionType = command.SubscriptionType
    };

    await _subscriptionRepository.AddSubscriptionAsync(subscription);

    return subscription;
}
}



Program.cs


services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining(typeof(ICommand<>)))



Hope this helps. Thanks
